# labelCol issue with inline layout in antd form/form.item in version 5.4.6

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm using the labelCol in the form and form.item as in the following code, previously i was using the antd version 5.2.2 and it was working perfectly fine but recently i upgraded it to 5.4.6 and its not working properly. Its causing issue in style. I attached the UI results as well.

```
<Form name="basic" layout="inline" onFinish={onFinish} labelCol={{ span: 24 }} initialValues={initialValues} autoComplete="off">
<Form.Item label={label} labelCol={{ span: 24 }} name=''>

</Form.Item />
```

Please someone share some comments to resolve this.

This is another image in which style is fine.

This is the link where its working fine:
[https://codesandbox.io/s/form-layout-antd-5-4-7-forked-6rfhmt?file=/demo.tsx:207-230](https://stackoverflow.com)

Another link with same code and version 5.4.6 where style is not fine:
[https://codesandbox.io/s/form-layout-antd-5-4-7-forked-8kfr9r?file=/demo.tsx:207-230](https://stackoverflow.com)